# __security_init_cookie in Windows driver causes bugcheck KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

Something very strange is happening when I target Windows 8.1 when I compile my driver.

As soon as it loads, it crashes with bugcheck `KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`, first parameter 6, which means "`The stack cookie security cookie was not properly initialized by the loader`".

This may be caused by building a driver to run only on Windows 8 and attempting to load the driver image on an earlier version of Windows. To avoid this problem, you must build the driver to run on an earlier version of Windows".  **This error does not occur when I target Windows 7.**

I was able to find exactly where this error is occurring.  It is happening in the `__security_init_cookie` function which is called by `GsDriverEntry`.

```
INIT:000000014000C1B4 __security_init_cookie proc near        ; CODE XREF: GsDriverEntry+10p
INIT:000000014000C1B4                 mov     rax, cs:__security_cookie
INIT:000000014000C1BB                 test    rax, rax
INIT:000000014000C1BE                 jz      short loc_14000C1DA
INIT:000000014000C1C0                 mov     rcx, 2B992DDFA232h
INIT:000000014000C1CA                 cmp     rax, rcx
INIT:000000014000C1CD                 jz      short loc_14000C1DA
INIT:000000014000C1CF                 not     rax
INIT:000000014000C1D2                 mov     cs:__security_cookie_complement, rax
INIT:000000014000C1D9                 retn
INIT:000000014000C1DA ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INIT:000000014000C1DA
INIT:000000014000C1DA loc_14000C1DA:                          ; CODE XREF: __security_init_cookie+Aj
INIT:000000014000C1DA                                         ; __security_init_cookie+19j
INIT:000000014000C1DA                 mov     ecx, 6
INIT:000000014000C1DF                 int     29h             ; Win8: RtlFailFast(ecx)
```

From this disassembly we can see that it performs 2 checks.

```
The first check checks if rax (__security_cookie) is zero and the 
second check compares it to 2B992DDFA232h.
```

However, `__security_cookie` is declared in my binary as `2B992DDFA232h`, and thus the interrupt should never be called, but somehow it is.

Comment: Did you declare `__security_cookie` manually? That code will **fail** (calls `RtlFastFail`) if `__security_cookie == 2B992DDFA232h` because it means that the cookie was left at its default value (insecure). There's code elsewhere (look for `KeTickCount`) that should be computing a new random security cookie.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct @nneonneo, I did interpret that control flow incorrectly.  To answer your question, no, I did not manually declare __security_cookie.  I took a look into the Windows 7 binary and it did indeed compute a new cookie with KeTickCount, however equivalent code is completely missing on the Windows 8.1 binary.

Comment: I assume you are testing the driver on a Windows 8.1 system?  The question doesn't say.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 8+ is able to generate security cookie for loaded executable image. Location of security cookie is stored in `LoadConfig` data directory in `PE` header so that Windows loader can easily replace it.
The reason is that the OS should be able to generate the cookie in safe way (for example using `RDRAND` instruction if available and/or other random entropy sources). Also there is no need to copy cookie initialization code to every driver.

If your driver targets Windows 8 (and newer) it expects that OS will initialize the cookie. Therefore it raises `BSOD` if cookie wasn't changed.
On the other hand if your driver targets older OS (Windows 7), compiler has to generate code that initializes cookie if it wasn't already initialized by OS. This way the driver is compatible with all Windows versions.

I haven't found any official description of this Windows 8 feature, but here is article that describes it:
[Reversing Windows8: Interesting Features of Kernel Security](http://hitcon.org/2012/download/0720A5_360.MJ0011_Reversing%20Windows8-Interesting%20Features%20of%20Kernel%20Security.pdf)

> When loading the kernel driver, Windows 8 calls MiProcessLoadConfigForDriver to
>   generate security cookie, locates old security cookie in PE and replaces it.
>
> New Windows8 kernel drivers will check if their security cookies are already
>   replaced.

Answer (score 4):

For those who build drivers in Visual studio 2015. If you need your driver to be compatible with Windows 7.

1. You need Windows 10 sdk and matching WDK (revisions must match).
2. In your driver project use default Target Platform Version i.e. 10.x.x.x and default Platform Toolset i.e. WindowsKernelModeDriver10. DO NOT change anything here. And don't touch _WIN32_WINNT definition.
3. The platform is specified at Driver Settings - General. There you specify Target OS Version - Windows 7, Target Platform - Desktop. AND ONLY THIS ONE. If you specify Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, it's still going to crash in the security cookie check code.

p.s. the driver will still be compatible with windows 10, 8.1 and 8.